# Font Awesome icons disappear after hyperlink to target="_blank"

Tags: html, font-awesome

Couldnt figure out how to get Font Awesome into A JSFiddle but this is simple enough...

After clicking a link that used target="_blank", all font awesome icons disappear from the original page... am I going crazy??

```
<i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Comment: Any chance that you can show a complete html-page that suffers from the same problem? Also, what browser are you using and have you tested the same page on other browsers?